# XCode UITesting check if a text field exists

Tags: objective-c, testing, ui-testing

I can't find any way to check if a text field exists without trying to get it which then fails the tests and shows an error if it can't be found. `No matches found for TextField`

#### Current code

```
XCUIElement *usernameTextField = app.textFields[@"username"];
```

#### Reason/detail

I've got a Objective C UITest in XCode which logs into my app in `setUp`  and logs out in `tearDown` however sometimes my app is already logged in when the test starts (if the simulator has been used for anything else in the meantime). I'd like to be able to check to see if the username textfield exists in my `setUp` and then if it doesn't I can skip the login or call my `logout` function and continue as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Obj-C but here's how it would work in Swift.

```
let usernameTextField = app.textFields["username"]
if usernameTextField.exists {
    do something
} else {
    do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Swift, which can easily be converted to Obj-C:

```
// given:
// usernameTextField exists
// The username that is possibly entered there is "username".

// then:
if usernameTextField.value as! String == "username" {
  // logged in
} else {
  // not logged in
}
```